# how to deploy blackberry application on blackberry 10.2 simulator

Tags: java, blackberry-10, ripple

1. I am using ripple emulator. I created simple config.xml file and
   index.html file, i run      application using ripple emulator.
2. Using ripple emulator i build app and created HelloWorld.bar file.
3. Now, i have to deploy this application on Blackberry10 simulator, i
   installed blackberry 10   simulator.
4. please tell me the steps to deploy blackberry app on blackberry10
   simulator
5. I am using below link, i am not getting how to configure simulator

   https://developer.blackberry.com/develop/simulator/simulator_configuring.html

Answer (score 0):

There should be a deploy to simulator in the ripple emulator. Just give it the IP of your VM running the simulator and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Go to settings, and fill all the information needed. in the Launch/target field, you can select either the simulator or the device then provide the IP. the password is needed only when deploying to a device.

then go to the build section in Ripple simulator (bottom right) and click Package/Package & Launch.

Make sure the simulator is running before you click on Package and launch. and make sure you provided the correct IP of the simulator.

keep an eye on the command line running to see if there are any errors.